# Stop Gridview from treating "-" as punctuation?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview which in one column is displaying MAC addresses. Instead of displaying them in one row, its putting them in a column as wide as the "MAC" header column. If I remove the `-`s, then it extends the column width and displays it as one row. Is there any way to have this happen with the `-`s included?

Field in question looks like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MAC" SortExpression="MAC">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MAC") %>' 
       Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MAC") %>'
                                        Wrap="False"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterStyle Wrap="False" />
<HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
<ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: it isn't technically treating them as newlines, its treating them as punctuation, which allows it to word wrap.

Comment: Thanks, modified title, wasn't exactly sure what it was doing. Even with disabling wrap it's still wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How have you disabled wrap? Consider:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="SomeGuid" 
                DataField="SomeGuid" 
                ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
```

Does the column or grid have enough room to fit unwrapped?

Comment: Modified original question. I've ever tried setting the width to something like 1000 and it doesn't respond to that either.